# How can I create a function that creates a unique string from inputs str a and b?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript and I was wondering if anyone could help me on this question?

With strings `a ="xyaabbbccccdefww"` and `b="xxxxyyyyabklmopq"`. I'm supposed to create a function called longest that takes in these two inputs, i.e. `function longest(a,b)` and return a string that is unique and sorted.

So far my code is:

```
function longest(s1, s2) {
  let val = new Set((s1 + s2));
  let newStr = "";
  for (let item of val){
  newStr += item;
  }
  let newestStr = function(newStr){
    return ((newStr.split('')).sort()).join('');
  };
  return newestStr;
}

let a = "xyaabbbccccdefww";
let b = "xxxxyyyyabklmopq";
let val1 = longest(a, b);
```

But this generates `function (newStr) { return newStr.split('').sort().join(''); }` when I try to print val1. Instead it should return the string `abcdefklmopqwxy`.

Can someone explain to me where I went wrong? and is there a more efficient way of solving this, cuz the `((newStr.split('')).sort()).join('');` is NlogN which is very long.

Thank you!

Comment: the best solution to a lot of programming issues - `debug it`. Check the return value of `longest` function

Comment: You have defined a function called `newestStr` rather then a variable.  You can either replace that function by what the function is returning, or call the function before returning it

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the help! Managed to solve the issue by calling newestStr directly ```function newestStr(newStr){
    return ((newStr.split('')).sort()).join('');
  };```. But i do not understand why can't I call the function in the variable.

Comment: You're returning the `newestStr` as a function, not as a result of its execution. I guess you expected to do something like `return newestStr(newStr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is correct. But the `longest` function returns a `function` instead of the value. Adjust the return statement as:

```
  return newestStr(newStr);
```

Comment: omg! thanks! i didnt know you could call it this way!!!